# has_many association after_load type callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I want to record interactions between a group of individuals each modelled as a message with a sender and a receiver:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => 'Individual', :foreign_key => 'receiver_id'
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'Individual', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
end
```

I would like to add an interface whereby I can record a message being sent from the point of view of an individual:

```
@bob.messages.new(:direction => 'to', :correspondent => @jane)
```

Ideally this would behave exactly like an active_record has_many association. I decided to subclass the message model, aiming to create something that could respond in this way - it didn't seem appropriate to just add the methods to the Message class, as the object needs to have some knowledge of its 'principal individual' (in the case above @bob) in order to know which Message to create.

```
class Individual < AcitveRecord::Base
  has_many :received_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'receiver_id'
  has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'

  has_many :messages, :class_name => 'MyMessage',
                  :finder_sql =>'SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver_id = #{id} OR sender_id = #{id}',
                  :after_add => :set_user

  def set_user(my_message)
    my_message.principal_user = self
  end

  class MyMessage < Message
    attr_accessor :principal_user  
    def correspondent
      @principal_user == receiver ? sender : receiver
    end

    def direction
      @principal_user == receiver ? "to" : "from"
    end
    ... other methods ...
  end
end
```

This does almost what I want. Unfortunately the after_add callback fires only when new objects are added to the messages collection, not when each object is loaded into the association for the first time.

As far as I've found no 'after_load' association callback exists. Is there something else I can use, or a better way to approach this situation?

Comment: What are you doing with the `MyMessage` objects? Is it like a message board where people can delete stuff from their inbox and outbox?

Comment: The situation described is a simplest one I can think of that captures the problem. I'm not actually trying to create a message box. Think instead of watching a population and making a note of each time they send each other a message. The `MyMessage` objects only serve to provide a different interface for creating `Message` objects, but one that is aware of one of the objects it belongs to.

Comment: When would you need to create a message from the point of view of the receiver? Messages are created when they're sent.

Comment: Say you're creating an app for a high school teacher to record when children send notes to one another. They probably won't know the content of the note, but they might see that Bob passed a note to Jane. And one of the specifications might be that you add this with the syntax `@bob.messages.new(:direction => 'to', :correspondent => @jane)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, in the end I delved into ActiveRecord and came up with the following:

```
 has_many :messages, :class_name => 'MyMessage',
                  :finder_sql =>'SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver_id = #{id} OR sender_id = #{id}',
                  :after_add => :set_user do
                    def find_target
                      messages = super
                      messages.each {|m| m.principal_user = proxy_owner}
                      messages
                    end
                  end
```